# How to change the format of a single column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a very simple MySQL query:

```
'SELECT * FROM `mytable`'
```

One of the columns in `mytable` is a date column. When I use the query above, I get the date as a date and time togather. 
Is there a way to receive all records like I'm doing with the above query, using *, but change only the date format to have the date only without the time?

Comment: No, you have to list the columns individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it, but you could add a new one to the result.

```
select *, DATE_FORMAT(`date_column`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS foo from `mytable`
```